# Keycloak token doesn't include mapped user session note on first login

Tags: keycloak

I have created a custom IDP and whenever I login I need to set a User Session Note which is mapped in Keycloak and then added to the access token. The problem I am facing is that this User Session Note is not saved the first time a user logs in. It works the second time, and third and so on, but on the first login the user does not simply get the key/value added to the token.

The login succeeds every time, however it is missing the user session note that I wanted to be mapped on the token.

I'm not sure what the problem is. The IDP is set up to have a custom "First Login Flow" which has Create User If Unique (alternative) and   Automatically Set Existing User (alternative). Maybe there is something here that I need to change so that it also includes User Session Notes on token for the first login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone finds a more delicate solution than I did, but I managed to solve this by a little hack.

I noticed that in the provider I could override the method "preprocessFederatedIdentity" and when listing the User Session Notes there I saw that they do in fact exist on the session. However, when reaching the method "authenticationFinished" (also overridden) they have been cleared from the session (the clearing seems to happen right before method "updateBrokeredUser" is reached). This odd behaviour only happens on the first login.

What I then noticed is that User Attributes stored on the context however are not cleared. They persist, and this was key to my solution. Then what I did was simply to loop through all of the User Session Notes in the method "preprocessFederatedIdentity" and store them as User Attributes (with the key prefixed with "UserSessionNote:"), and in the latter step "authenticationFinished" I add them to User Session Notes again. I also stored all of the keys of the User Session Notes in a User Attribute called "UserSessionNotesKeys" as a comma separated string so that I could simply split that string and loop through the attributes in the "authenticationFinished" method and then add them to User Session Notes.

This basically solved my issue in a generic way, and also made sure it would work if future User Session Notes were added.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you need to implement the `importNewUser()` method in your extension of `AbstractIdentityProviderMapper` and set your notes on the `authenticationSessionModel` there.

Inside of the authenticated method, where `preprocessFederatedIdentity()` is called, Keycloak checks if `federatedUser == null`. At this point, you are in the state of preprocessing the federated user; it does not yet exist. Keycloak then calls `resetFlow()` within this if block where it then clears auth notes from the `authenticationSessionModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you saved a user session note:

```
authSession.setUserSessionNote("MY_NOTE_1", "MY_NOTE_1_VALUE");
```

You can use this strategy in the `preprocessFederatedIdentity` method to pass missed user session notes; copy them into context data:

```
@Override
public void preprocessFederatedIdentity(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, IdentityProviderMapperModel mapperModel, BrokeredIdentityContext context) {
    ...
    context.getContextData().putAll(context.getAuthenticationSession().getUserSessionNotes());
    ...
}
```

Then you can retrieve this information in the `importNewUser` method with context data:

```
@Override
public void importNewUser(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, UserModel user, IdentityProviderMapperModel mapperModel, BrokeredIdentityContext context) {
    ...
    // Here context.getAuthenticationSession().getUserSessionNotes() is empty; use context data to retrieve informations:
    String userSessionNoteValue = context.getContextData().get("MY_NOTE_1");
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps, it works and there should be no problem storing information in context data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Following the answers from Adrian / Anton I went to find out the mentioned "if" at the org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService::authenticated(BrokeredIdentityContext) where this call is made:

```
// Redirect to firstBrokerLogin after successful login and ensure that previous authentication state removed
AuthenticationProcessor.resetFlow(authenticationSession, LoginActionsService.FIRST_BROKER_LOGIN_PATH);
```

To solve this I've made my own IdentityProviderMapper where at the preprocessFederatedIdentity I "cache" the userSessionNotes which I'm interested in keeping and then on importNewUser / updateBrokeredUser I restore these sessions notes.

The importNewUser is called after running the first login from external IdP, while the updateBrokeredUser is called in all other scenarios, most notably also when a Merge accounts is performed. In this case of merging accounts the authenticationSession is also reset, and therefor its also needed to update it at the updateBrokeredUser.

One final point to take in consideration is the SyncMode which the plugin handles. By default, at the IdentityProviderMapper, the FORCE sync mode is not supported and therefor it might be needed to add it as well (or just return true for any syncMode).